# SharePoint Search filters on verticals across all sites

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, search-results, sharepoint-search, microsoft-search

I setup search filters in Microsoft 365 on All and Files verticals, they only appear when I search through the Organization scope, but when I search from a hubsite or a site, the filters don't appear. Someone guided me to the documentation where I need to setup filters on every single site. But it's a problem if we want to show filters on all newly created sites by default. Is there a way to have custom filters on verticals appear on all sites automatically?

Answer (score 1):

There are two search vertical levels, organization level and site level.

In the each site, you should add search verticals manually. There is no option to automatically add search verticals in all newly created sites.

**Manage organization-level verticals:**

1.In the Microsoft 365 admin center, go to the Verticals page in the Customization section.

2.Select an existing vertical and click edit or click add to create a new vertical.

3.After moving through the configuration steps, you can review and save the vertical.

**Manage site-level verticals:**

1.In the SharePoint site where you want to manage verticals, open the settings panel by clicking the gear.

2.Select Site information, and then select View all site settings.

3.Look for the Microsoft Search section, and then select Configure search settings.

4.In the navigation pane, go to Custom experience and then select Verticals.

5.Select an existing vertical and click edit or click add to create a new vertical.

6.After setting your configuration, you can review and save the vertical.